# Why does a PC-to-AS400, ASCII FTP transfer result in very large file growth on the AS400 side?

Tags: ibm-midrange

GIVEN: I am a novice on the AS400 platform, at best

PROBLEM: We need to transfer variable width, pipe-delimited ASCII files from a Windows 2003 server to an FTP server running on V6R1. The files arrive and are properly translated to EBCDIC, but they are huge. A 3.5Mb file becomes a 200+ Mb member. A 9Gb file fails because we bump up against some manner of quota.

INTERESTING FACT: When done in binary mode (no translation), the file appears on the server side as FILENAME.FILE with one member named FILENAME.MBR. The transfer size is correct, but the file is not readable by native tools because of the ASCII encoding.

INTERESTING FACT: This has been tried on three V6R1 machines with the same results. So I'm fairly certain this is normal behavior that I just do not understand well.

My gut feeling here is that the server is extending the file as it adds new rows to it -- but I really don't have a better guess that that at this point. Has anyone seen this behavior before, and do you know what it takes to avoid it?

Thanks in advance to anyone taking the time to contribute. I do appreciate it.

Comment: The record length is set to the longest line in the header, then every line will take that space too quickly adding up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IBM i FTP server can either deal with objects in the "classic" QSYS.LIB file system (where you have objects such as files residing in a single layer of libraries) or stream files on the Integrated File System (a hierarchical file system similar to what's used in Windows and Unix).

It sounds like you're sending the file into a Physical File (PF) in the QSYS.LIB file system.  A PF has fixed-length records, so you're probably seeing some slack space at the end of most records.  You can see how many records are in the PF and the record length using the `DSPFD` CL command.

If you want to send the file to a PF, the FTP server defaults to name format 0, which is the QSYS.LIB file system.  In this mode you'd send to a PF such as this:

```
SEND myfile.txt DMCLIB/MYFILE.MYMBR
```

If you want to send the file to a stream file, you have to first send a command to the FTP server:

```
QUOTE SITE NAMEFMT 1
```

This switches the FTP server into IFS naming mode.  As a result, when you send the file you'll need to specify what directory you want to send it to.  For example:

```
SEND myfile.txt /home/dmc/myfile.txt
```

If you're sending up variable-length records, that IFS stream file will have no slack as you'd see in a Physical File.

If the pipe-delimited file contains a single layout, you can use the `CPYFRMIMPF` CL command to map it into a PF with an actual record format, which is probably the more "native" way to do it.  If it's a more complex file format, however, you might have to write an ILE RPG program to convert the stream file into whatever form it needs to be in.  [Here are some great tutorials](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/ifs.html) on accessing stream files from ILE RPG.

Also note that you can see some interesting help info from the IBM i FTP server using the `QUOTE HELP` command while connected from a command-line FTP client.

Comment: So, it's the slack in the physical file that is causing the large sizes? As you mentioned, we are sending to a physical file using NAMEFMT 1 so the mid-range folks can read it in the classic fashion.

Comment: Yes, that's my guess.  If you know how wide an average record is and compare it to the record length of the physical file, you should get an idea of the amount of slack.  Also note that if you're sending to a PF you're using NAMEFMT 0.

Comment: Technically, the `QUOTE SITE NAMEFMT 1` is not required as long as the server is not explicitly configured to force `NAMEFMT 0` as the default **and** your initial reference in the FTP script to any file system path is in `NAMEFMT 1` format. By default, the server will automatically switch to the first use of one of the two formats. After any initial format is set, it can only be changed by issuing a `NAMEFMT` command to the server.

Answer (score 3):

There are many [file systems](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiq/rzaiqftpconvn.htm) available on the AS/400.  The standard file system is really DB/2.  A library is a database/schema, a physical file is a table, a member is a [table partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29), and a logical file is an index/view.  The IFS is a normal stream based file system.

Ascii mode will map text ending with an EOL character (CR/LF) to a single physical file record.  Binary mode ignores EOL characters and streams as much raw data as will fit in each record.  For more information see the [File Transfer Protocol reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiq/rzaiqreference.htm).

Use the [DSPFD](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/dspfd.htm) command to view the file definition.  The *Maximum record length* will indicate the fixed length record size.  Multiply that by the number of records to be uploaded to calculate how much space it will require once uploaded.  Chances are the 'mid-range folks' created a file for you with an absurdly long record length.  It should be trivial for them to recreate the file with a more appropriate record length so that you don't waste too much space.

There is a maximum number of records defined when a file is created to prevent the disk from filling up.  You can find those values in the [DSPFD](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/dspfd.htm) command as *Initial number of records*, *Increment number of records*, and *Maximum number of increments*.  Those values can be changed as required using the [CHGPF](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/chgpf.htm) command with the [SIZE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/chgpf.htm#CHGPF.SIZE) parameter.

Another option would be to upload to the IFS file system and have the 'mid-range folks' process the file directly from the IFS.  Here's a Scott Klement tutorial for [Working with the IFS in RPGIV](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/ifs_ebook/).